# Are there any bounded elementary functions which are not Riemann integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, definite-integrals, riemann-integration, elementary-functions

Let an [elementary function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) be a function which is made up of sums, products, and compositions, of finitely many polynomial, rational, trigonometric, and exponential functions, and of their inverses.

I'm wondering whether there exists an elementary function which is not Riemann integrable, but not due to it being unbounded? That is, does there exist an elementary $f(x)$ such that it is bounded on some finite interval $[a,b]$ and yet its Riemann integral $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx$ doesn't exist? I am allowing for $f(x)$ to be undefined in some of the points of $[a,b]$.

My thoughts so far:

- From Lebesgue's criterion for Riemann integrability, in order for a bounded $f(x)$ to be integrable on $[a,b]$ its points of discontinuity must be of measure zero. So we are looking for an elementary $f(x)$ with infinitely many points of discontinuity, in fact uncountably many. These points of discontinuity mustn't be asymptotes, because we're looking for bounded $f(x)$.
- One way to get an elementary function with a jump discontinuity is to define e.g. $f(x)=\frac{|x|}{x}$ (this indeed fits the definition of an elementary function since we can write $|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$). I thought of somehow composing this with a periodic function to get an infinite number of such jump discontinuities in a finite interval, but this would still give us only a countable number of such points (and hence still have measure zero).

Is there an example of a (bounded) elementary function which is not Riemann integrable? Is there a reason for such functions to never exist?

Comment: It seems that elementary functions are piecewise continuous, and thus integrable if bounded. Although I just saw your comment that there can be infinitely many, so maybe there's more to it.

Comment: "I am allowing for $f(x)$ to be undefined in some of the points of $[a,b]$." You need to be more specific about it, otherwise a trivial example will be $\frac{1}{x-x}$, which is not Riemann integrable since it's not defined on any point at all.

Comment: @jjagmath Good point. Maybe there's another trick to get non-asymptote discontinuities in elementary functions that are not only of the form $\frac{|x|}{x}$ and such that the function *is* defined in its points of discontinuity? If so then the whole discussion of where we allow the function to be undefined can be avoided.

Comment: I tried to do that some time ago, I think it's not possible because all the functions involved are continuous where they are defined.

Comment: @jjagmath Right! Elementary functions are continuous wherever they are defined, so if $f(x)$ is elementary and $x_0$ is a point of discontinuity then $f(x_0)$ is necessarily undefined. So the whole question rests on allowing the function to be undefined in some points, which as you've noted does not make sense to do in general. Thanks. I'm not deleting this because I think I might wonder about the same question again in a few years and it will be useful for me to recall this logic in one place in case I forget it. Do you want to post an answer? If not I might do this later on. Thanks again.